# Python - Sort files based on timestamp

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list which contains list of file names, i wanted to sort based on timestamp, which ( i.e timestamp ) is inbuild in each file name.

Note: In file, Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T084521_1424543480.tar.gz --> 2015-02-20T084521 represents as "year-moth-dayTHHMMSS" ( Based on this i wanted to sort )

Input file below:

```
file_list = ['Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T084521_1424543480.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T095845_1424543481.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T095926_1424543481.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T100025_1424543482.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T111631_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T111718_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T112502_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T112633_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113427_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113456_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113608_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113659_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113809_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113901_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113955_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-03-20T114122_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T114532_1424543486.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T120045_1424543487.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T120146_1424543487.tar.gz',  
'Hello_WR_2015-02-20T084709_1424543480.tar.gz',  
'Hello_WR_2015-02-20T113016_1424543486.tar.gz']
```

Output should be:

```
file_list = ['Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T084521_1424543480.tar.gz',  
'Hello_WR_2015-02-20T084709_1424543480.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T095845_1424543481.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T095926_1424543481.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T100025_1424543482.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T111631_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T111718_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T112502_1424543483.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T112633_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_WR_2015-02-20T113016_1424543486.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113427_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113456_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113608_1424543484.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113659_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113809_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113901_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T113955_1424543485.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T114532_1424543486.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T120045_1424543487.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-02-20T120146_1424543487.tar.gz',  
'Hello_Hi_2015-03-20T114122_1424543485.tar.gz']
```

Below is the code which i have tried.

```
def sort( dir ):
   os.chdir( dir )
   file_list = glob.glob('Hello_*')
   file_list.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
   print("\n".join(file_list))
   return 0
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You state that you are trying to sort on the filename, but your function is using getmtime, which is the time that file itself was last modified. https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-os.path.html#l2h-2177 . You need to decide on an approach, either the file timestamp or the information encoded in the filename, and consistently pursue it.

Comment: @sparky: I wanted to sort based on timestamp encoded in the filename.

Answer (score 4):

So this worked for me and it sorted files by created time that did not have the time stamp in the name;

```
import os
import re

files = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if (file.lower().endswith('.gz'))]
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

for file in sorted(files,key=os.path.getmtime):
    print(file)
```

Comment: Why lower it if you only check the extension?

Comment: Also, it now gets sorted by the timestamp of the file and not by the name of the file, what can be different. Not likely but still.

Comment: This assumes you're in the target folder. If not, `os.listdir(".")` can be updated easily, but I don't know how you fix `key=os.path.getmtime` (this also requires file to be in the current dir).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One detail... the files are already sorted by date on line 5 `files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)`. Thus, the second call to `sorted` can be avoided :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to sort based on the filesystem-stored modified time, not the filename time.

Since your filename encoding is slightly sane :-) if you want to sort based on filename alone, you may use:

```
sorted(os.listdir(dir), key=lambda s: s[9:]))
```

That will do, but only because the timestamp encoding in the filename is sane: fixed-length prefix, zero-padded, constant-width numbers, going in sequence from biggest time reference (year) to the lowest one (second).

If your prefix is not fixed, you can try something with RegExp like this (which will sort by the value after the second underscore):

```
import re
pat = re.compile('_.*?(_)')
sorted(os.listdir(dir), key=lambda s: s[pat.search(s).end():])
```

Comment: check the file names:
They are named Hello_Hi and Hello_WR, when sorted, it will sort it based on that and not on the other part

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that, which means the naming convention is not sane. I'll fix that.

Comment: cool! I stumbled upon the problem myself, finding out this solution doesn't work in the old scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

You could write list contents to a file line by line and read the file:

```
lines = sorted(open(open_file).readlines(), key = lambda line :        
line.split("_")[2])
```

Further, you could print out lines.